# How to correctly execute asynchronous calls to mongodb in javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

I have an operation kinda like so:

```js
const results = Promise.all([
    myColl1.find(query1).sort(sort).limit(limit).toArray(),
    myColl2.find(query2).sort(sort).limit(limit).toArray(),
]);
```

However, it seems the results are completely unexpected. After looking what might possibly going on, the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/) states:

> Warning: Because asynchronous calls directly modify the cursor, executing asynchronous calls on **a single cursor** simultaneously can also cause undefined behavior. Always wait for the previous asynchronous operation to complete before running another.

The "single cursor" part seems to imply it might be possible to do this with two separate cursors? I'm actually not too sure of the technical details but, wouldn't the fact that `myColl1` != `myColl2` mean they're separate cursors? I've actually been considering joining the collections, so if they were the same, would it be possible to use separate cursors? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is not in a cursor. Calling `myColl1.find()` with even the same collection should return separate cursor. You however should not do `let cursor = myColl1.find(); cursor.sort(); cursor.limit();`. What are the "completely unexpected" results you get?

Comment: The queries are for obtaining paginated batches. When I kick off both actions simultaneously with`Promise.all()`, `results[0]` never fetches anything more than the exact same first batch each time, whereas `results[1]` functions as expected and obtains subsequent batches.

However, when I remove both db calls from `Promise.all()` and `await` each one individually, the batches update as expected. This does mean though that I must wait for the first batch request to complete before I can even begin to fetch the other batch. I'd like to obtain both batches simultaneously if possible.

Comment: Just for sure, do you use `await`? (`const results = await Promise.all(...)`)

Answer (score -1):

Do you use await? I made some changes to what you originally posted:

```js
const [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
  await myColl1.find(query1).sort(sort).limit(limit).toArray(),
  await myColl2.find(query2).sort(sort).limit(limit).toArray()
]);
```

I hope this helps ✌

Comment: The helper functions `Coll1` and `Coll2` are pointless, they're doing the same thing as the OPs code does (but also they handle errors incorrectly)

Comment: Alright, thanks for pointing that out @Bergi. I have updated the answer to fix those issues

Comment: Now the `Promise.all` is pointless, you're just doing two sequential calls.